# What percentage of numbers can be written as $n=p*m$ with p prime and $p>m$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

What is the chance* that a random positive integer $n$ is the product of a prime $p$ and an integer $m>0$, with $p>m$

Or in other words: when $n$ has a prime factor greater than it's square root

- more formally, the amount of numbers up to N satisfying the condition, divided by N, and then letting N go to infinity.

From simulations it seems that:  chance* $= 0.718 =$(?) $ 2-e$

Comment: It's $\ln(2)\approx 0.693147181$.  See [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html).

Comment: I have tested 1.000.000 random integers drawn as random_int(1, 20000000000), if n  = p^2, I discard n and draw again (these should have density 0 anyway, right?) I'm really converging to 0.717.. How can that be?

Comment: I haven't checked your code (and don't intend to).  Nor have I checked the proof of the claim I linked to, though it's been peer reviewed and published so I presume it is accurate.  Perhaps there is a bias for small numbers that persists out as far as you checked, that happens some times.

Comment: But, I am confused by your post.  If $\delta$ is the density we are looking for (the density of the set of natural numbers whose largest prime factor exceeds the square root), then the published claim is that $\delta =\ln (2)$.  You appear to be asserting that $1-\delta\sim .718$ which would be very far off.

Comment: And why do you discard numbers of the form $p^2$?  Those are perfectly good natural numbers.  The property you seek doesn't hold for them, of course, but I see no reason to discard them.

Comment: Ah, I take it back.  The references in the link I provided don't seem to lead back to published papers.  But it's a result I have seen quoted before, so perhaps better references exist.  I'll take a quick look.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357112/how-does-one-prove-that-the-density-of-unusual-numbers-is-ln-2) are better references.  I note that Noam Elkies provides a very nice proof in a comment.

Comment: I discarded them because I first looped through each of the integers in ascending order and I figured that these boundary cases $m=p$ where slowing down the convergence. Anyway, I now test each and every random int I draw and it still the same.  I guess the upperbound of  random_int(1, 20000000000) is the issue, removing some 0's maker $\delta$  significantly greater, but a higher bound makes my simulation too slow

Comment: Again, though, is your simulator saying that $\delta\sim .717$ or that $1-\delta$ is about $.717$?  Your post claims the latter.

Comment: Thanks lulu, you were right, I mistakingly flipped the chance $\delta$. I'll read what you sent me after I try myself a bit more to solve it.  I think the problem is equal to the following: take a large prime P. We play a game where you start with 1 USD. You get 1/p_n chance to multiply it by p_n. If you got lucky, you can play the p_n multiplier again, until you fail. then you move on to $p_{n+1}$ multiplier, etc etc. What's the chance you end up with more than $P$ USD?

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A064052 and there are some references to the literature.